# Emacs for Erlang with vi like keybindings and handy short references?

Tags: emacs, erlang, keyboard-shortcuts, vi, key-bindings

I have come accross vi-style keybindings for Emacs, but my past experience in mixing Lisp based config in .emacs file for enabling various modes etc., hasn't been very pleasant so far.

Read several articles on Emacs + Erlang, but is there something that might be slightly easier for folks familiar mostly with vi (and who are unfamiliar with Lisp)?

The entire set of possibilities (keybindings) is quite overwhelming. Is there a condensed key-map/shortcuts reference specially relevant for Erlang development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `vi` and a command line. There are numerous people doing that and it seems to work just fine for them. Even though I use Emacs, it is not the Emacs-erlang interaction I use. Rather I usually just have a separate Erlang shell and then I load modules in that shell with the `l()` command for interaction.

---

Answering your questions one by one:

- Debugging in Erlang is funny. Firstly, if your program is kept *functional* you will find that you need much less debugging to figure out what the program does incorrectly because you can simply write small tests for each of the numerous functions to test its correctness. And you can add those into unit-test frameworks.

  As soon as you add multiple processes to the mix you will find that traditional debugging doesn't work anymore anyway. The trick is then to trace and assert, and you will need to learn a way to read programs without running them and see where they go with a debugger.

  That said, try to execute `debugger:start()` in an Erlang shell :) There are also the tracing systems and *redbug*, a 3rd party tool built on top of them (part of the `eper` suite).
- Profiling can be done with one of the 3-4 profilers: `cprof`, `eprof` and `fprof` are all slightly different in scope and in how much impact they have on your program and if they can be run on a production system or not. I tend to use `eprof` and I have a knob in my program which will spawn an eprof and then attach it at program start.
- Try `appmon:start()` in a shell.
- The standard vi-way of browsing large code bases is to create `tags`-files so you can jump to the definition point of the thing-under-the-cursor. Emacs can do the same. I have a `make tags` target to create these files so I can easily make jumps around in the source code. When jumping you have a stack of the former jumps so you can return to the point you jumped *from* later on.
- Finally there are tools like `xref` which can be worked to create call graphs and find odd things in the code. It will require some coding on your part, but it does provide you with the necessary tooling.

Comment: yeah, I use vim and the command line. As for sharing or splitting windows and whatnot, fitting my environment into tmux or screen works fine.

Comment: @i-give-crap-answers and @rvirding, thanks for your responses. Good to know that people are managing pretty well with vi. However how about debugging, profiling ? I understand that managing with vi, for a smallish (I'd say less than 10K LOC) project, created by self or a small tight teach, should be manageable. However if you want to study, dig-deep into someone else's code -- and rather quickly, a IDE with features like source-code browsing makes the navigation lot easier/quicker. Don't you think ? Or you've found some solution for that as well ?

Comment: Dumped an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Viper mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) provides Vi-style keybindings. That's probably the easiest way to start. Enabling a new mode in your .emacs is a pretty fundamental part of using Emacs, so it's a learning hurdle best cleared early!

The [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) contains more detailed information about making individual changes to your keybindings.

You may find [Xah's keybinding tutorial](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html) helpful, as it provides many examples.

Comment: thanks for your response. Viper was indeed one of the modes I'd found. However my confusion was what happens when I load viper-mode, erlang-mode, distel without any keybinding remapping ? Won't there be some clash/confusion ?  In the end, my objective is to quickly get productive with Erlang, and not master Emacs :-) ... a wicked shortcut maybe!